# search a struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

`void search(struct _data *BlackBox, char *name, int size)` - this function
will get the dynamic array of struct passed to it, the name we are looking
for, and the size of the array. This function will then search the dynamic
array for the name.

```
typedef struct _data
{
    char* name;
    long number;
} _data;

int scan(FILE *(*stream));
struct _data *load(FILE *stream, int size);
void search(struct _data *Blackbox, char *name, int size);

int main()
{
    int size = scan(&stream);    
    rewind(stream);
    _data *data = load(stream, size);

    char input;
    printf("Please Input Search Name: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    while (input != NULL)
    {
        search(data, input, size);
    }
}

void search(struct _data *Blackbox, char *name, int size)
{
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name,Blackbox[i].name) != 0)
        {
            printf("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Name Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following output

```
Output:
LINES: 2
ron 7774013
jon 7774014
Please Input Search Name: ron

RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault: 11; real time: 2s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Comment: Note that for most purposes, you should consider names starting with an underscore as reserved for the implementation to use.  You'll get away with it surprisingly often, but not forever.  And it'll hurt when you don't get away with it.

Comment: @user3337714 easiest solution is to run in debugger and see where exactly it've crashed. But anyway, I don't think it even compiles - your `input` have type `char`, but `search` expects `char*`, and `scanf` to `char` (with format `%s`) is almost certainly incorrect. You should compile code with warnings turned on (at least `-Wall` for gcc/clang).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Identifiers beginning with a *double* underscore, or an underscore followed by a capital letter, are reserved for the implementation.  A single underscore and a lowercase letter are fine.

Comment: @EdS.  ISO/IEC 9899:2011 ¶7.1.3 Reserved identifiers: — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
underscore are always reserved for any use.
— All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers
with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._
The use of `struct _data` is an identifier beginning with an underscore in the tag name space and is reserved; the use of `_data` for the typedef name is an identifier beginning with an underscore in the ordinary name space and is reserved.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Huh, didn't know that bit of the spec, thanks.  Good thing I never named my types that way eh?

Comment: @EdS. You are far from being the only person who doesn't (didn't) know the second bullet point in 7.1.3.  As I said, you can actually get away with it a lot of the time, but when it bites, it hurts.  It's usually when you're porting existing code to a new system — so you have several years worth of code to fix all of a sudden.  (Incidentally, the section number and the wording were the same in C90; the wording was the same in C89 but the section number was different.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your main function you have "char input;", and "scanf("%s",input);". That's wrong, because the %s specifies a string parameter, but input is a char variable. So whatever is typed in by the user is stored at some random place in memory.

Change the declaration of input to something lime "char input[1000];". And you'll have to do something about your while loop too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `search` function before you try to use it.

The compiler should even warn you about that implicit declaration.

Comment: I just did. Thank you for pointing out. But now I am getting the input option, but no output

Answer (score 0):

If you get a segmentation fault then one the following applies:

1. Your struct `Blackbox` in `search` function is not pointing to a valid memory location and thus the `Blackbox[i]` produces the fault
2. The `name` member of the struct is not pointing to a valid memory location and thus the `Blackbox[i].name` is producing the fault
3. The size of the `Blackbox` array is less than `size-1`.

To do this, use a debugger and check the `Blackbox` where is pointing. Then check the `Blackbox.name` where is pointing. Then, check if there is anything to the `Blackbox` array up to `size-1`. I assume that either will be null. Perhaps an error in the assignment of the `load` function or a wrong usage of the `size`.